# Ketu in 12th House

Tags: astrology

I've heard that Ketu in the 12th House signifies Moksha, and the possibility that this life might be the last one. Is it really so? What other factors are to be taken into account? I also have Saturn with Ketu in my 12th House. Would that be a hindrance?

Comment: And which chart - Lagna or Navmansa?

Comment: Lagna. I have heard that in Navamsha chart the 12th from Karakamsha gives Moksha if its Ketu, but I don't have that in Navamsha chart. Only in my Lagna do I have Ketu in the 12th house from Ascendant.

Comment: Saturn is BTW my Rashi Lord. My Rashi is Makara.

Comment: Ketu in 12th house in lagna chart will offer Moksha only if you do spiritual practice. Ketu in 12th house merely wont fetch you Moksha unless you find a guru and meditate. Ketu in 12th house indicates social isolation which is must in intense spiritual practice. I have Ketu in 12th house in navamansa chart, and when I received diksha of Gurumantra from my Guru and chanted it a lot , I got astonishing spiritual experiences. Once Mohammed the prophet visited me and blessed me! Planets decide a lot of things but finally Purushartha(Efforts) has it's own significance too.

Comment: Yes I do my own spiritual practices, but I have yet to find a Guru. I have bhakti for Ram and worship him as prescribed by Ram Himself to Shabari. The 9 ways of Bhakti. Nevertheless I have yet to come in contact with a Guru, for which I am earnestly calling on him, whoever, wherever he is. Its said that in due time a Guru finds his disciple. At the moment I am a student so I cannot go to pilgrimage places on my own. But after I get into a job, I will.

Answer (score 2):

According to Jaimini, you will have to check your Karakamsha which is the sign occupied by Atmakaraka in your D9 chart. If 12th house from the Karakamsha happens to be in the sign of Aries or Saggitarius along with **Ketu**, one gets Moksha.

> KriyachAshyorvisheshaiN 
>     If Karakamsha is Mesha or Dhanus with benefics there, the subject gets moksha. If Mesha or Dhanus happens to be the 12th from Karakamsha and Kethu is there the person will get Moksha.
>    
> Adhaye 1, Pada 1. Sutra 70

Answer (score 1):

Check whether this Ketu has got an aspect from Jupiter. 
if there is any, then, this may be the last birth.

8th house indicates time of death or total life span.

12th house indicates soul's interested path/journey after death.

if Ketu is in 12 with an aspect from Jupiter, then soul never likes to reincarnate again, and travels to supreme soul.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism! Nice to see your answer, but its mandatory to back your answer with references so that readers are benefited from authorized sources. Otherwise, it looks like an opinion based answer which is not allowed here.