# Relation of Rahu in 12th house and Liberation/Moksha

Tags: astrology, moksha

Below is half learned knowledge from internet. If you start Googling "Rahu 12th house ..." then one auto-complete will suggest "Moksha"!

Rahu is considered the master of material desires. When travels to 12th house (hence Ketu in 6th house), it would find itself lack of those resources.

Such position usually creates situations where person is forced to have disinterest (*vairAgya*) from the material desires. Such mindset is considered an ideal candidate for Moksha as it pacifies the *Rajas* (passion) mode ([BG 6.27](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20845/1049)).

**Questions**:

- How is the 12th house of Rahu calculated?
- Does it have any relation to liberation?

---

Related: [Ketu in 12th House](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24431/ketu-in-12th-house)

Comment: I personally liked [this post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-impact-of-Rahu-in-the-12th-house/answer/Shreyas-Ramakrishnan) from Quora. Other answers are also informative.

Comment: The two questions you mentioned in the body are totally different. For the calculation, you should ask separate question or can go to [astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/11573/1769).

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't have any relation with *moksha*.

The reason being, any combination of *moksha* has to be checked from the position of *Atmakaraka in the Navamsa chart*.

*Rasi chakra* shows the *physical body* of the native, which obviously can not be liberated. It is the *atma* that attains liberation.

*Rahu*, moreover is a planet that is responsible for *bhoga*, therefore causes bondage and makes the *atma* go through continuous cycles of birth and death.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct to an extent. Rāhu in 12H from AL imparts religious wisdom as said in BPHS Chapter 30,

> 38. If Rāhu is in the 7th/12th from Lagna Pada or aspect one of the said houses, the native will be endowed with spiritual knowledge and be very fortunate.

As an illustration, Below is the chart of a religious luminary Śrī Rāmkṛśṇa Paramhaṃsa whose Rāhu is in 12H from AL.

[image]